# Hibernate Subselect with class inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two objects with same fields, but from different tables (foo_something and bar_something in fact not plain tables, there are results of several join operations). I use `@Subselect` hibernate annotation for fetching data. Can I make class structure like this, but which working fine? This class structure doesn't work because annotations doesn't inherit. If I use `@Inheritance` annotation, I get error `Unknown column foo_somethingca0.DTYPE`

```
class Something {

    @Id @Column Long id;
    @Column String name;
    @Column String description;

    //getters, setters, constructors

}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT id, name, description FROM foo_something")
class FooSomething extends Something {

}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT id, name, description FROM bar_something")
class BarSomething extends Something {

}
```

**UPD.**

Thanks, @HenryMartens, I added annotations `@Entity` and `@Inheritance` with `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy, and made class abstract, now it's working fine:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class Something {

    @Id @Column Long id;
    @Column String name;
    @Column String description;

    //getters, setters, constructors

}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT id, name, description FROM foo_something")
class FooSomething extends Something {

}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT id, name, description FROM bar_something")
class BarSomething extends Something {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DTYPE` in Hibernate is the discriminator column. It is used to tell the difference between some objects that are persisted in the same database table like your example.
You can add an discriminator column with the [`@DiscriminatorColumn`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html) annotation.

On the concrete classes you can use [`@DiscriminatorValue`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html) to set the value of the discriminator column for the annotated class.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS ) 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISC", discriminatorType=STRING, length=20)
class abstract Something {

    @Id 
    @Column 
    Long id;

    @Column 
    String name;

    @Column 
    String description;

    //getters, setters, constructors 
}

@Entity
@Table("FOO_SOMETHING")
@Immutable
@DiscriminatorValue("FooSomething")
class FooSomething extends Something {

}

@Entity
@Table("BAR_SOMETHING")
@Immutable
@DiscriminatorValue("BarSomething")
class BarSomething extends Something {

}
```

Comment: My base class `Something` - it's not a table, it's simple base class with list of fields, getters and setters, which i don't want to duplicate in `BarSomething` and `FooSomething`, that's why I cannot use `@Table` annotation in base class cause `SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [SOMETHING]`. This class an abstract.

Comment: @Denis Gavrus Then you have to make your `Something` class abstract. You can use `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` to get a table for each `FooSomething` and `BarSomething`.